# Reading and Typing in a new File IO

Tags: python, io

Why does the text not show up when I click on the file_io_reverse.ipynb file??

##I am trying to read 'file_io.ipynb' and put the reverse of it into 'file_io_reverse.ipynb', this code doesn't work at all

```
f = open('file_io_reverse.ipynb', "a")
with open('file_io.ipynb', "r") as f2:
    for i in f2:
        x = i[::-1]
        print(x)
        f.write(x)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "this code doesn't work at all"?

Comment: Yes sorry, it doesnt work with what I want it to do. It prints to the console in the original file the reversed text. But I want it to print to the new file

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what that means. The file *file_io_reverse.ipynb* **will** contain the lines from *file_io.ipynb*. Your mixture of ways of opening and closing files is inconsistent but not functionally incorrect

Comment: suggest to dedent ```f.close()``` to main scope outside ```with``` as improvement but not relevant to problem

Answer (score 2):

As @olvin pointed out, your mixture of ways of opening and closing files is inconsistent but not functionally incorrect and should work.

What are you trying to open the `file_io_reverse.ipynb` file in?

IPYNB notebooks are plain text files formatted using **JSON**, making them human-readable and easy to share with others. So if you are trying to reverse contents of each line in the file and trying to save it in another file, then that would make the new **ipynb** file invalid.

Try opening the file in a **text editor**, and it should have the reversed lines for each line in the `file_io.ipynb`.